# How do I add an array of names in a single event?

Tags: azure-application-insights

In my application I can add more than one person at a time. I want to log multiple names in a single event.

I have a bunch of data is "Persons". Persons contains Name

In my application I can add more than one person at a time. I want to log multiple names in an event

What is the best way to log the data in AI?

The only way I can think of this, but its not the ideal way

```
foreach (Persons person in persons) {

if (person.IsNew)
 {
    personName += Person.Name + ",";
 }

metricRecorder.AddProperty("personNameAdded", personName);

}
```

The above is not ideal way as when the data gets into AI, it would require regex to separate the name or even get the count of the names etc...

I can't find anything in the documents, how would I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add each name as a `property` of `EventTelemetry`.

A sample code like below, you can modify your code as per the sample:

```
        TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient { InstrumentationKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxx" };

        EventTelemetry eventTelemetry = new EventTelemetry();
        eventTelemetry.Name = "event_1";

        List<string> names = new List<string>();
        names.Add("ivan");
        names.Add("jack");
        names.Add("nancy");
        names.Add("tina");
        names.Add("sarah");

        int i = 0;
        foreach (string n in names)
        {                
            eventTelemetry.Properties.Add("name_"+i, n);
            i++;
        }
        client.TrackEvent(eventTelemetry);
```

Then in the logs of application insights:

[image]